# "Easy TO me" or "easy FOR me" in this context

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-meaning

I have heard both of the expressions :

> 1. This work is easy **to** me.
> 2. This work is easy **for** me.

What are the different uses of **to** and **for** in this context?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `easy FOR me` case is fine.

I don't know if `easy TO me` is *technically* incorrect or not.  But I am a native speaker of American English, and I wouldn't say it that way--and I don't hear others say it either.

You can be *easy on* someone, but you wouldn't (properly) say you were *easy to* someone.  What sounds correct would be:

```
This work seems easy to me.
This is easy work.
```

When you use `IS XXX TO`, the general pattern is that it should be active.

```
Her cat is mean to me.
```

Trying to use `easy` here suggests that the easiness itself is acting on you--where you are the object.  It doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

> This work is easy TO me.

Using **To** here indicates that that work is easy according to **my** view and opinion.

> This work is easy FOR me.

While using **For** indicates that the work is easy based on my abilities and qualifications. So, I **can** do it since I find it easy to do.

Comment: *"Using To here indicates that that work is easy according to my view and opinion."* I mention in my answer that my feeling as a native speaker is that to say this, you should say something like `seems easy to me`.  It doesn't sound correct if you just say `is easy to me`; otherwise it sounds more like the easy is "acting" upon you.

Comment: I can't exactly imagine the sentence with the meaning "acting upon you", but yes, you are right. Thanks for informing me of that.