# "seem" vs. "is"

Tags: word-usage

Per an ELL [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/196871/109190), the following sentence might not be grammatically correct

> This work **is** easy to me.

at least, the expression is unusual to a native English speaker.

In the meanwhile, a similar one sounds natural to him.

> This work **seems** easy to me.

I have been treating "*seems*" as "*is + a bit uncertainty*". Cambridge Dictionary verifies my feeling by giving this definition of "*seem*"

> to give the effect of being; to be judged to be

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20easy%20to%20me%2Cseems%20easy%20to%20me%2Cis%20easy%20for%20me%2Cseems%20easy%20for%20me&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20easy%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseems%20easy%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cis%20easy%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bis%20easy%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20easy%20for%20Me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseems%20easy%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20easy%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseems%20easy%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cis%20easy%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bis%20easy%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20easy%20for%20Me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseems%20easy%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0) also justifies that sense.

[image]

So, is it idiomatic to substitute "*to be*" for "*seem*" when getting rid of uncertainty?

Comment: It certainly does seem to be the case. 
        "He seems to be drunk = he appears to be drunk." -->
meaning that *by the look of it* he's drunk but we are not 100% certain. 
        "He is drunk." -->
we are sure that he, actually, IS drunk. Certainty.

Comment: @Fermichem Thanks for nice examples. Would I view of what you said as a YES to my question, the last sentence in my OP?

Comment: @based on the extensive research you've done, I'd have to say, yes. :) I'd wait for others to answer the question though, if I were certain about my "answer" I would posted as an answer after all. :)

Comment: Yes, I think that's right. Substituting "to be" for "seem" gets rid of uncertainty.